# Laravel 6 CORS policy issue with API

Tags: php, cors, laravel-6

Here is what i tried

**Middleware**

```
 return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Accept, X-Token-Auth, Application')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
```

**API route**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['cors', 'auth:api']], function() {
Route::options('{any}');
Route::post('user/profile','UserController@profile');
```

**Kernel.php**

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
```

But still, I am getting this error in API call from another origin.

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Any reason?

Comment: did you find the solution? i can't find the solution. all solutions not working. fed up.
I dont want to modify the file bootstrap/app.php

Comment: same here, any solution with this one? I'm also using Laravel 6

Answer (score 5):

The Easiest Solution
Go to bootstrap folder and open app.php file. Then just add these lines at the top of the file.
app.php

```
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
```

Another Solution:

```
      php artisan make:middleware Cors
```

Now open Cors.php from App\Http\Middleware folder and replace handle() function with this code:

Cors.php

```
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
      return $next($request)
          ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
          ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE,

        OPTIONS')
          ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorizations');
  }
```

Lastly, open Kernel.php from App\Http folder add the below line to the $middleware array:

```
  protected $middleware = [
      ...
      \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
  ];
```

Now run the application and call API from anywhere.

The tutorial is over. Thank you.

Answer by [MyNotePaper](https://www.mynotepaper.com/easiest-way-to-allow-cors-in-laravel)

Comment: I think this is Laravel 6 version bug,  and this trick work for me

Answer (score 2):

Require the fruitcake/laravel-cors package in your composer.json and update your dependencies:

```
composer require fruitcake/laravel-cors
```

**Global usage**

To allow CORS for all your routes, add the HandleCors middleware in the $middleware property of **app/Http/Kernel.php** class:

```
protected $middleware = [
    // ...
    \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
];
```

**Configuration**

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag="cors"
```

Now update the config to define the paths you want to run the CORS service on, (see Configuration below):

**config/cors.php**

```
'paths' => ['api/*'],
```

More details https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors

Comment: HandleCors middleware should be at the top of `$middleware`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63913814/11792577

Answer (score 1):

hello if you are using laravel 6
maybe all the above resolves will not work

so you should to put the code below inside the file
RouteServiceProvider.php :

```
public function boot()
{
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
    parent::boot();
}
```