# Laravel CORS with Fruitcake

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-redux, cors, laravel-middleware

I make **react** project with **laravel** Back-end ... I have a **CORS** problem, I do everything like on link below, with fruitcake.

[Laravel 6 CORS policy issue with API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59194484/laravel-6-cors-policy-issue-with-api)
but still not working.

#### cors.php:

```php
        'paths' => ['api/*'],

    /*
    * Matches the request method. `[*]` allows all methods.
    */
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    /*
     * Matches the request origin. `[*]` allows all origins.
     */
    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    /*
     * Matches the request origin with, similar to `Request::is()`
     */
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    /*
     * Sets the Access-Control-Allow-Headers response header. `[*]` allows all headers.
     */
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    /*
     * Sets the Access-Control-Expose-Headers response header.
     */
    'exposed_headers' => false,

    /*
     * Sets the Access-Control-Max-Age response header.
     */
    'max_age' => false,

    /*
     * Sets the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header.
     */
    'supports_credentials' => false,
```

And, kernel middle-ware is:

```
        protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,

        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    ];
```

what else could be the problem?

Answer (score 11):

Here are some gotchas when using `fruitcake/laravel-cors`:

- Put `HandleCors` middleware at the top of `$middleware` in `app/Http/Kernel.php`:

```php
protected $middleware = [
    \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
];
```

Putting it at the bottom or somewhere between won't work because requests might be rejected by other middlewares with higher priority.

- Do **NOT** die or exit in controller.

For example the following won't work:

```php
Route::get('/cors-test', function() {
   dd("This won't work");
});
```

Because `Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::handle` method adds relevant headers **AFTER** handling request:

[**Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors.php**](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors/blob/master/src/HandleCors.php)

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    // --- omitted

    // Handle the request
    $response = $next($request); // <--- if you die here

    if ($request->getMethod() === 'OPTIONS') {
        $this->cors->varyHeader($response, 'Access-Control-Request-Method');
    }
    
    // you will never reach here
    return $this->addHeaders($request, $response);
}
```

`dump` does not work either

- Clear config cache after changing `app/config/cors.php`:

```
$ php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: In my case was a `dump` in a FormRequest method

Comment: In my case it was the redirect from www. to non-www, I was making a request to www version which converted POST requests to GET

Answer (score 4):

The `Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class` is troublesome. Just remove it from everywhere and add these 3 headers in `api.php` route file on the top.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Authorization, Accept,charset,boundary,Content-Length');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Comment: can you tell us why it is "troublesome"? Your solution does not handle preflights correctly

Comment: It comes with a route middleware registered as `cors`. Right? So what is a good idea to use it. By putting it as a route or routegroup middleware. It just fails to add the required headers until you add it to the global middleware in the kernel file.

Comment: ok, but that is the laravel way to do it. Btw laravel 7 uses the fruitcake component as default, so there is no reason to avoid it. The way you do it will probably give an 404 on preflights, so this is not a solution.

Comment: I also worked with it on laravel 7 itself. In my case I tried like everything. But it didn't work. So if you have it working, please post an answer.

Comment: Thanks @AnkitSingh. Your solution works for me and the fruitcake thingy was indeed the culprit.

Answer (score -1):

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

Make sure your permissions are setup correctly (eg. storage is writable)

Answer (score -1):

Actually ,just remove dd and die command from you code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact, that's what @bravemaster already pointed out and on the other hand I can't see the thread owner doing `dd()` or `die()` in any of the code samples.

Answer (score -2):

Add `credentials: 'same-origin'` to your request header in the react App