# Laravel CORS for subdomain API

Tags: laravel, graphql, cors, laravel-lighthouse, laravel-8

I'm using Laravel to serve a GraphQL API, using Lighthouse. Everything works fine when I use grapqhl as a URI in the main domain, but when I use it in a subdomain eg. `grapql.app.test` I get the next error:

> Access to fetch at 'http://graphql.app.test/' from origin
> 'http://app.test' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

My `config\cors`:

```
'paths' => ['api/*','graphql'],
'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
'exposed_headers' => [],
'max_age' => 0,
'supports_credentials' => false,
```

How can I solve this?

I'm using laravel 8.

Comment: I dont know why the * doesnt worked for me. Here it works when I define the origin. ```'allowed_origins' => ['http://app.test'],```. Is the path you are trying to access inside one of the paths you defined? This URI is root ```http://graphql.app.test/```, what happens when you try to access ```http://graphql.app.test/api``` ?

Comment: @JonathanMartins I have my API running in `http://graphql.app.test/`and I try to use it in `http://app.test`. There's where I get the CORS error. I tried to add `http://app.test` to `allowed_origins` but didn't work.

Comment: If you make an ajax request from ```http://app.test``` to ```http://graphql.app.test/api``` what you get?

Comment: @JonathanMartins I get the same error

Comment: @JonathanMartins ok, the solutio was add `'\'` to `paths` and `'*'` to `allowed_origins`. Also works if I use this `'allowed_origins' => ['http://app.test'],`. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If anyone is having trouble with this, you need to add the paths that you will use. In my case was `/` due that my API is in `grapql.app.test`.

The resulting code:

```
'paths' => ['api/*','graphql','/'],
'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
'allowed_origins' => ['http://app.test'],
'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
'exposed_headers' => [],
'max_age' => 0,
'supports_credentials' => false,
```

Answer (score 1):

Incase someone is facing this issue with Laravel 8+, ensure that the API URL doesn't end with a slash on the client request i.e. instead of https://someapi/endpoint/ it should be https://someapi/endpoint