# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource when trying to register

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel-9

The error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/localhost:8000/api/register' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

In the controller I have:

```
public function register(Request $request){
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'name' => 'required|max:40',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:200|unique:users,email',
            'password' => 'required|min:8',

        ]);
        if($validator->fails()){
            return response()->json(['validation_errors'=>messages()]);
        }
        else{
            $user = User::create([
                'name'=> $request->name,
                'email'=> $request->email,
                'password'=> Hash::make($request->password),
            ]);
            $token = $user->createToken($user->email.'_Token')->plainTextToken;
            return response()->json([
                'status'=>200,
                'username'=>$user->name,
                'token'=>$token,
                'message'=>'Registration Successful'           ]);
        }
    }
```

The register component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import swal from 'sweetalert';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from "../Navbar";
import Footer from "../Footer"
import "./css/login.css"

function Register() {

    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [registerInput, setRegister] = useState({
        name: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        error_list: [],
    });

    const handleInput = (e) => {
        e.persist();
        setRegister({...registerInput, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    }

    const registerSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        const data = {
            name: registerInput.name,
            email: registerInput.email,
            password: registerInput.password,
        }

        axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(response => {
            axios.post(`localhost:8000/api/register`, data).then(res => { 
                if(res.data.status === 200)
                {
                    localStorage.setItem('auth_token', res.data.token);
                    localStorage.setItem('auth_name', res.data.username);
                    swal("Success",res.data.message,"success");
                    navigate.push('/');
                }
                else
                {
                    setRegister({...registerInput, error_list: res.data.validation_errors});
                }
            });
        });
    }
    const goBack = () =>{navigate('/login')}

    return (
        <>
        <Navbar/>
            <div className='center'>
                <form onSubmit={registerSubmit}>
                    <h1>Register</h1>
                    <br></br>
                    <div className="form-group mb-3">
                        <input placeholder="Username" type="text" name="name" onChange={handleInput} value={registerInput.name} className="form-control"  />
                        <span>{registerInput.error_list.name}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group mb-3">
                        <input placeholder="Email" type="text" name="email" onChange={handleInput} value={registerInput.email} className="form-control"  />
                        <span>{registerInput.error_list.email}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group mb-3">
                        <input placeholder="Password" type="password" name="password" onChange={handleInput} value={registerInput.password} className="form-control"  />
                        <span>{registerInput.error_list.password}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group mb-3">
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button onClick={goBack}>Back</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <Footer/>
        </>
    );
}

export default Register;
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If you just want to test on localhost, then allow origin * on the server.

Comment: Have a look at this plugin https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors. And then you can follow the answers in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60168052/laravel-cors-with-fruitcake